# Get one of checkbox value with multiple checkbox using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I'm trying to get checkbox value from multiple checkbox.I have code as below:

```
 <input class="ng-pristine ng-valid" type="checkbox" name="ch" value="a" ng-model="todo.done">
 <input class="ng-pristine ng-valid" type="checkbox" name="ch" value="b" ng-model="todo.done">
 <input class="ng-pristine ng-valid" type="checkbox" name="ch" value="c" ng-model="todo.done">
 <input class="ng-pristine ng-valid" type="checkbox" name="ch" value="d" ng-model="todo.done">
```

what I want: when I check on checkbox,it will alert the value of checkbox.
I have jquery code as below:

```
  $('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
$('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    //the problem in here when I alert it will display many time with the other value of checkbox
    //what I need: I want to get only value of it when I check on it.
        alert($(this).prop('value'));
    }
});
});
```

Anyone please kindly help me, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work like this

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        alert($(this).attr('value'));
    }
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/CT3uT/)

Comment: `$(this).attr("")` and `$(this).is("")` can be `this.`

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to loop through the checkbox elements

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function () {
    if (this.checked) {
        alert(this.value);
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/h74Tq/)

Answer (score 0):

ok i know in php if you want to have the same name for you checkbox you need to put it in an array

```
<input class="ng-pristine ng-valid" type="checkbox" name="ch[1]" value="a" ng-model="todo.done">
```

etcetera, so im sure you have to loop through the array in jquery as well, sorry i dont konw the exact code off hand. :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function () {
     alert($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Look more into `each` jQuery function... I think what you need is parameters inside the `each` function like `each(function(i,element) {})` where `i` behaves as the iterator for the checkboxes and `element` can be used to reference that checkbox. I think the issue is because you're using `(this)`, which is not referencing the exact checkbox.

I hope I led you in the right direction.

Comment: if you include more then `i led you in the right direction`, i will `+1`.

Comment: ok...then you will be able to do almost every kind of thing related to the checkbox within the DOM structure....using parent and siblings..  for simple alert do alert(element.val())

Comment: i meant explain your answer better, and also add something to help the "asker" in his specific case.

Comment: although really the loop is unnecessary.

Comment: ok, my first post in stackoverflow didn't go well....loop will allow for more flexible approach if you would require to add other stuffs later.

Comment: ye happens sometimes in life, (you may want to delete it), better luck next time... enjoy and learn from it!

Comment: (may be i would leave it on, just to piss you off)...stackoverflow is awesome. keep posting!!

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
$(this).val();
```

its working.

Answer (score 0):

try the following code.
in your $(this) refers to the elemnets of $('input[type="checkbox"]').each, hence it repets for all checkbox. I have changed  **change** event to **click** as this one is good to use rather than change.

```
  $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {

    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
               alert($(this).val());
    }

 });
```